# Error with displaying sql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to print out average values hourly from the past 24 hours from my database, but for some reason all I get is 0's.

Can help anyone?

It connects successfully into the database, but doesn't print out any "real" values.

```
$sql= "SELECT date_time, AVG(temperature2) FROM dbname(changed).weather_a
WHERE date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE( date_time), HOUR (date_time )";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = array();
$rows['cols'][]=array('label'=>"date_time","type"=>"string");
$rows['cols'][]=array('label'=>"temperature2","type"=>"number");

if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $temp = array();
        $temp["c"][] = array("v"=>$row[date_time]);
        $temp["c"][] = array("v"=>floatval($row[temperature2]));
        $rows["rows"][] = $temp;
    }

    $myJSON = json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    echo $myJSON;
}
?>
```

Comment: use a column alias `AVG(temperature2) as avg_temperature` and use that alias within your PHP code.

Comment: Some sample data could be helpful

Comment: thanks alot for the help!  :)